# Cambiar el nombre de un formulario en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, vb

Estoy haciendo una app en Visual Studio 2022, una aplicación de formulario de Windows Forms, entonces, necesito hacer varios archivos de formularios, entonces, cuando los creo, me salen como "Form1.vb" y yo le quiero cambiar el nombre, pero no puedo. Intenté cambiar el nombre del archivo, funcionaba, pero al compilar, me daba error de compilación y me salía una ventana diciendo que hubo un error de compilación y que si quiero usar la versión estable.

Comment: Hice unas pruebas, y cuando creo un Form a mi me pide un nuevo nombre antes de crearlo y una vez creado le cambio el nombre y funciona correctamente. Quizás tu error está en otro lado

Comment: File/Save as...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías abrir el designer.vb para cambiar la referencia del nombre allí tambien, eso puede ser que sea el problema de compilación que te muestra en ele mensaje.